# Is there a mono appindicator/notification area icon available for XChat?

Tags: xchat

Despite the steady reports of mono icons appearing for programs on sites like *OMG! Ubuntu!*, the popular XChat still seems to be missing a mono icon.

In addition to that. how can we recommend it for inclusion into the repository package?

Comment: What do you mean  by a "mono" indicator?

Comment: Mono as in black and white that goes with Ubuntu's mono icon theme.

Comment: @nickguletskii, it's as @miloshadzic says.

Comment: @nickguletskii, no. See the default appindicators of Ubuntu in the default theme are all white in colour. I want XChat's icon white as well, otherwise it looks foreign.

Comment: @nickguletskii, er... there's no icon at all in the screen shot. In any case, I'm simply looking for an icon, nothing beyond that.

Comment: @nickguletskii, I'm simply looking for a mono icon, I don't need XChat inside messaging menu or anything.

Comment: @Oxwivi Oh, I see, I just thought you wanted an indicator... Sorry. Time to install xchat then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use the mono icon

You will need administrator privileges (`gksu`, `sudo`, etc) to apply system-wide.

[image: XChat]

1. Save the [mono icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zgls.png), shown above.
2. Go to Terminal or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> execute this command `gksu nautilus`.
3. Navigate to the directory `/user/share`.
4. Paste the icon you downloaded into it.

Restart XChat if running.

[image: The new XChat icon on the panel]

I think it's bug but you won't be ale to see the icon immediately, you need to click where it's supposed to appear first.

#### Create mono icons

**Requirements**

- Inkscape
- Administrator privileges (`sudo`, `gksu`, etc)

**Method**

1. Open the terminal, type in `gksu nautilus`. This will launch Nautilus with superuser privileges.
2. Go to `/usr/share/`, and create a directory called `xchat` there.
3. Go to `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/24/` and open up `xchat-panel.svg` in Inkscape (as superuser too, open from the superuser Nautilus Window opened in first step).
4. On the menu, go to File, then Export Bitmap...
5. Click on Page, then make the Width and Height input boxes have a value of 48.
6. Click on Browse. Navigate to `/usr/share/` then select `xchat.png` and save.
7. Export.

[image: Inkscaping the XChat icon]

Comment: Can you post the resulting icon on Devianart or something? Instead of doing it over, it'd be easier to share and of course you'll get the credit. :)

Comment: @Oxwivi didn't think of that... Done.